# Opencv cv2.BFMatcher doesn't see similarities

Tags: python, opencv

I try to compare to images:[image]   and[image] , for example.

Code is below.

My output: '(len(matches))' = 0 - no matches. Also, output image is without lines(flags), and why no matches?

I tried to do it with pictures from example code, it works.

And no one from this methods work:

```
cv2.NORM_HAMMING
cv2.NORM_HAMMING2
cv2.NORM_L1
cv2.NORM_L2SQR
cv2.NORM_MINMAX
cv2.NORM_RELATIVE
cv2.NORM_TYPE_MASK


img1 = cv2.imread('3.jpg',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('3q3.jpg',0)
orb = cv2.ORB_create()

kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

matches = bf.match(des1,des2)
matches= sorted(matches, key=lambda x:x.distance)
print(len(matches))
for m in matches:
    print(m.distance)

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches[:10],None, flags=2)
cv2.imshow('s',img3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

There didn't appear to be any keypoints detected for the cropped image.  If you lower the `edgeThreshold` (default=31), it allows it to detect more features.  This is done by:

```
orb = cv2.ORB_create(edgeThreshold=8)
```

This resulted in keypoints for the cropped image and it was able to make a match:

[image]

Comment: OK,thanks but unfortunately this method with 'edgeThreshold=8' doesn't determine remained three 3 on the picture. If i decrease this value, I get similarities with 'Q'.